# "at the right time" or "at a right time" in context

Tags: articles

Tell me please what is the difference between the following sentences.

> It is ok to add supplementary exercises to the main lifts. Just do it at **the** right time.
>
> It is ok to add supplementary exercises to the main lifts. Just do it at **a** right time.

I did not ask which one is correct because I was listening to a podcast in which native English speakers used the indefinite article in the sentence. And it has really bewildered me because I thought that the definite article is always used before words like *right* or *wrong*. Could they make a mistake?

Comment: You should show an example of when you heard "a" there.  "The" is certainly the only correct way of saying it in the sentence you give.

Comment: @DanielRoseman *There is **a** right time for everything.* Granted, that is not an equivalent construction. As you say, the exact sentence given would be very awkward with **a** (although not actually ungrammatical.) But it would be useful if such a comparison were provided in the question so we could comment on the specific confusion. (The statement that **the** is always used in general is simply false.)